# How to secure my database on centos server

Tags: centos

I done my project and deploy on centos. i have craeted a encrypted database but on lamp sever database shows the password.when i run on wamp all the data of database is encrypted but when i use commands on server its show me the passwords.any one kindly help me in this regards,i dont have any advanced idea of databases security.thanks in advance

Comment: Encrypt your password before saving in database and decrypt it whenever you want to use it in you application.

Comment: @NitinDhomse There is huge numbers pf password,i am imoprt the details to the database using excel csv format,when details are inserted in db then it is in encrypted form.

Comment: Which server side technology you are using?

Comment: i am working on centos

Comment: I mean your application. Java, PHP or ?

Comment: i am using php and in database that is sql